# Cell with filter type SELECT not matching by EXACT condition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I've noticed that when you change `columnDefs` of a grid after they were initially created (in order to dynamically populate `selectOptions` of a cell that has filter type set to `uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT`) filter's `condition` will not be applied - grid will "guess" and set `condition` to `CONTAINS`.

Example scenario (like in provided [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Eoi6oNTB2bhzKnn3vVd?p=preview)):

1. define columnDefs
2. fetch info about columns that has to be filtered as a uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT` (from a service or so)
3. update column definition of a desired columns (set `cellFilter` and define `filter` object)
   3.1. eg. define `selectOptions` to have values 1, 2, 12
4. update columnDefs by calling `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = angular.copy($scope.gridOptions.columnDefs);`
5. load grid data

Result - when you try to filter by either 1 or 2, results with values {1, 12} and {2, 12} will appear among visible rows.

Note - specifying `condition: uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT` does not work (as stated above), but doing something like `$scope.gridApi.grid.columns[columnIndex].filters[0].condition = uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT;` will do the job, but I find it hacky.

Shouldn't cell of type `uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT` always be filtered with condition se to `uiGridConstants.filter.EXACT` ?

I've also opened an issue on ui-grid's github because I think this might be a bug, but SO is read more often so maybe more people will stumble to this problem here.